# How to redirect the class name from avro schema name in spring-cloud-stream-kafka-stream?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a consumer app for consuming a Kafka topic.
When the producer publishes the record of class type `Reservation` through Avro, it assigns the schema name as `my_reservations` on the schema registry.

In my consumer app, I set the config as

```
default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

and the processor as

```
@Bean
    public java.util.function.Consumer<KStream<String, Reservation>> process() {

        return input.foreach((key, value) -> {
                    System.out.println(" Value: " + value);
                });
    }
```

But I'm getting below error from the consumer because the `Reservation` classpath is `reservation.Reservation`.

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class reservation.my_reservations specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.`

How can I fix it? I'm using the functional way to create the consumer as mentioned in the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_functional_style).

Comment: Please share your schema and producer code as well - [mcve]